# Sidebar Overlaps Column

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

When scrolling horizontally, the sidebar overlaps the other column. I am using jQuery + CSS to achieve this. How can I prevent this overlapping?

Before user reaches div container:
http://prnt.sc/b9j4t6

When user reaches div container (how it should always look):
http://prntscr.com/b9j7mz

**Overlap Issue:**
http://prnt.sc/b9j56m

Code:

```
            var element = $('.price-container');
            var baseTop = element.offset().top;

            $(window).scroll(function () {

                var top = $(this).scrollTop();

                if (top >= baseTop)
                    element.css({"position": "fixed", "top": "10px"});
                else
                    element.css({"position": "", "top": ""});
            });
```

Comment: why not use `z-index`

Answer (score 0):

The reason the left container is overlapping the right container is because you are setting it to be `fixed`. This takes the element out of the normal flow of the page.

If you dont want it to happen you can either set up within your css a media query to say if your page is smaller than x `position: static;`

```
// change max-width: 480px to suit your screen size
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .price-container { position: static !important; }
}
```

Or in your javascript

```
var top = $(this).scrollTop(),
    width = $(window).width();

if (top >= baseTop && width >= [the point you want to break] ) {
  element.css({"position": "fixed", "top": "10px"});
}
```